# Change Export File Type

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script that allows me to save a mysql database table as a excel spreadsheet from a php webpage. But it needs to be saved as a PDF. I have looked around and cant find any fix to my code.

```
<?php


include "db.php";
$SQL = "Select Name, Email, Department, Cellphone, Extension  from contacts";
$header = '';
$result ='';
$exportData = mysql_query ($SQL ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $exportData );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
$header .= mysql_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
{
$line = '';
foreach( $row as $value )
{
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
    {
        $value = "\t";
    }
    else
    {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
}
$result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );

if ( $result == "" )
{
$result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Telephone List.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$result";

?>
```

Comment: You need to use a package like TCPDF to save it as pdf.

Comment: Try finding the Mime-Type for PDF documents and change this `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");` to `header("Content-type: pdf mime type");` also change the content disposition extension to .pdf from `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Telephone List.xls");` to `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Telephone List.pdf");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: You can also check the FPDF Library vary easy to use http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: @Abolarinstephen i found the mime type and tried it but when I try and open the downloaded PDF file it says error opening pdf.

Comment: It would not work because creating a valid PDF file requires requires much more than that. You can achieve this by using the FPDF Library very easy to use and implement http://fpdf.org